# How to use "§" in password string to do a http request?

Tags: php

I am trying to do an http request with the following URL:

```
$url = 'http://user:123§456@myexampleurl.php';
```

I get an error "Invalid url", I think, the problem is §. I'm not able change the password though. How can I use it?

Comment: You need to encode the URL.

Comment: Please, add details how do you use your $url variable. The answer is depended on a used library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your password (and maybe the username too if you don't guarantee that it only includes alpha-numeric ascii characters)

In your specific case, your password would be `123%A7456`, because the `§` will be replaced with `%A7` by `urlencode()`

```
$url = 'http://' . urlencode($username) . ':' 
          . urlencode($password) . '@myexampleurl.php';
```